# Reset lost Bitnami LAMP stack password on Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, passwords, virtual-machine, lamp, bitnami

I have deployed a Bitnami LAMP VM inside a instance group, with the use of `.yaml` and `.jinja` files, and I cannot seem to view the "bitnami-base-password" in "clustom metadata". Is there a way I can reset the password manually?

Any help with this would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

Instead of reseting the password, you can try obtaining the password from inside the machine. You will need to access the instance using a SSH connection and run these commands. Those files include the credentials' information:

```
sudo cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials
sudo cat /opt/bitnami/var/log/pre-start.log
```

You can find more information about how to obtain the credentials in the Google's instances here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/find-credentials/